# How do i create a table using Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to make a error message when an error occurs,

HTML:

`<div id="errorMessage"></div>`

I want this table inserted into the div:

```
<table id="error" style="width:900px;border-top: 1px Solid #B7B7B7;border-right: 1px Solid #B7B7B7;
   border-left: 1px Solid #B7B7B7;border-collapse: collapse;background-color:#E7E7E7;height:auto;">
 <tr>
   <td style="color:#CC0000;">
     Een of meerdere verplichte velden ontbreken.
   </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

I've tried this:

```
$("#errorMessage").append("<table id="error" style="width:900px;border-top: 1px Solid #B7B7B7;border-right: 1px Solid #B7B7B7; border-left: 1px Solid #B7B7B7;border-collapse: collapse;background-color:#E7E7E7;height:auto;"></table>");

    $("#error").append("<tr><td style="color:#CC0000;">Message</td></tr>
```

I cant find the correct way to do it can someone please help? 
Appreciated :)

Comment: I would suggest to create elements using `document.createElement()` (search MDN to know more about this) instead of writing all element HTML as string, because as string it seems really awful to read

Comment: `"Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list",` !!! Which div!?!

Comment: If your going to use double quotes in the markup - I would suggest you use single quotes in the wrapper string e.g. `$("#error").append('<tr><td style="color:#CC0000;">Message</td></tr>');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<style type="text/css">
    #error{
        width:900px;
        border-top: 1px Solid #B7B7B7;
        border-right: 1px Solid #B7B7B7;
        border-left: 1px Solid #B7B7B7;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        background-color:#E7E7E7;
        height:auto;
    }
    .tdinsideError
    {
        color:#CC0000;
    }
</style>
<div id="errorMessage"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var errorContent = '<table id="error"><tr><td class="tdinsideError">'+customMessage+'</td></tr></table>'; // if  custom message.
    var errorContent = '<table id="error"><tr><td class="tdinsideError">Een of meerdere verplichte velden ontbreken.</td></tr></table>'; // if no custom message.
    $(document).find("#errorMessage").html(errorContent);//method 1
    $(document).find("#errorMessage").html($("<table>").addClass("error").attr("id",'error'));//method 1
    $("<span>").addClass("fa fa-plus")
</script>
<!--
    <table id="error">
        <tr>
            <td class="tdinsideError">Een of meerdere verplichte velden ontbreken.</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
-->
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me out, this is very useful. I got everything fixed up and working! :)

Answer (score 0):

You are using " twice. Try using ' for the outer html markup and " only for attributes like id and style.

```
$("#errorMessage").append('<table id="error" style="width:900px;border-top: 1px Solid #B7B7B7;border-right: 1px Solid #B7B7B7;
border-left: 1px Solid #B7B7B7;border-collapse: collapse;background-color:#E7E7E7;height:auto;"></table>');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#errorMessage").append(`<table id="error" style="width:900px;border-top: 1px Solid #B7B7B7;border-right: 1px Solid #B7B7B7; border-left: 1px Solid #B7B7B7;border-collapse: collapse;background-color:#E7E7E7;height:auto;"></table>`);
$("#error").append(`<tr><td style="color:#CC0000;">Message</td></tr>`);
```

Have a look at your closing and opening quotes, the quote immediately exits the string when you populate an html attribute because you used a double quote (
    "
).

You could use a single quote as your opening quote or as I have in the code above a backtick.

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m287jehu/)